# Should I put all present positions on top, regardless of start dates?

Tags: resume

I currently have multiple employers. One of these employments is ending, but since I order by start date first and it is my most recent position (chronological), it would be placed on top. This means that my still present occupations are listed below a completed employment.

Is it appropriate to move my preset occupations to the top, breaking the chronological order by start date?

Comment: multiple employers or multiple contracts you are working on?

Comment: Why don't you change the order to chronological order by end date, descending? All current jobs would be at the top and then it would be most recently ended jobs below that. You can use order by start date to break the tie between jobs with the same end date.

Comment: I think present employments would have legitimate priority over any concluded employments. The only time it might be appropriate to put concluded employment before present employment, would be if the concluded employment is your main occupation and the present employment is a minor sideline. For example, if you're a professional accountant between jobs, you wouldn't put employment as "minor league football referee" as the top item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody cares.
I know it sounds strange: honesty is essential to the resume. But the point is, any solid hiring manager or in-house recruiter barely reads 90% of these. I "read" (mostly don't read) about 500 a week.

There's the 10% that stand out, and that's all the information they need to invite you to a phone screen. If they're super polite, they'll actually read your resume during the first two minutes of your call.

Stand out.
On top of your resume, put whatever makes you stand out, as a good fit for the particular positions.

If you're junior, select the one job that is a fit for your desired position. List the rest with minimal detail: company, position, dates, and one best accomplishment.

If you're senior (10+ yoe), describe no more than 3 last positions. Pick only what's most relevant to your new job. The rest are just filler for building up your yoe. You can list them as one-liners, no detail, unless it's especially useful to your desired role.

I keep repeating the part about your new role. That's because your fitness for it is all that really matters at the resume stage. Your history matters too, but only at the last stage of selection, when they do your background checks.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would break it into two sections "Current employment" - sorted by either amount of employed hours (i.e. whichever is your more significant employment) or by relevance to the position being applied to if  and then "Employment History" - for all your previous ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.